# how to use fgets and sscanf for integers in loop

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

Beginner with C here. I am trying to run a loop where strings and `ints` are entered into various fields of a `struct`. When prompted for a 'last name', the user can press enter with no other input and the loop should end.

The problem is that with this code, the loop doesnt end (last name and first name entry requests run together on the same line) and the value for salary always comes out wrong (0 or some large number)

```
while (employee_num <= 2)
{
    printf("Enter last name ");
    fgets(employee[employee_num].last_name, sizeof(employee[employee_num].last_name), stdin);                   

    if(strlen(employee[employee_num].last_name) == 0)
        break;

    printf("Enter first name ");
    fgets(employee[employee_num].first_name, sizeof(employee[employee_num].first_name), stdin);

    printf("Enter title ");
    fgets(employee[employee_num].title, sizeof(employee[employee_num].title), stdin);

    printf("Enter salary ");
    fgets(strng_buffer, 1, stdin);
    sscanf(strng_buffer, "%d", &employee[employee_num].salary);     
    ++employee_num;
    getchar();
}
```

If I try this code instead, I am able to exit the loop properly after the first run through it, but cannot exit after that (by pressing enter at the last name portion - perhaps a \n I cant seem to clear?):

```
char strng_buffer[16];
while (employee_num <= 5)
{
    printf("Enter last name ");
    fgets(strng_buffer, sizeof(strng_buffer), stdin);                   
    sscanf(strng_buffer, "%s", employee[employee_num].last_name);       

    if(strlen(employee[employee_num].last_name) == 0)
        break;

    printf("Enter first name ");
    fgets(strng_buffer, sizeof(strng_buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(strng_buffer, "%s", employee[employee_num].first_name);


    printf("Enter title ");
    fgets(strng_buffer, sizeof(strng_buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(strng_buffer, "%s", employee[employee_num].title);

    printf("Enter salary ");
    scanf("%d", &employee[employee_num].salary);        
    ++employee_num;
    getchar();
}
```

I am curious as to how to make this work as intended and what best practice would be for entries like this (ie use of sscanf, fgets, etc)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the fix mentioned by Abhijit, why transform the first into the second? Are you aware that the second behaves differently to the first, because of the addition of `sscanf`? If your intention was to shorten the first, the second seems quite bulky. Rather than adding `sscanf` to the situation, why not shorten the first by declaring a `struct employee *e = employee + employee_num;` and using that repetitively, instead of `employee[employee_num]`?

One "best practise" regarding `fgets` is to check it's return value. What do you suppose [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fgets.html) might return, if it encounters `EOF`? What do you suppose [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fgets.html) would return if it's successful?

One "best practise" regarding `scanf` is to check it's return value. In regards to the return value of `scanf`, I suggest reading [this `scanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) carefully and answering the following questions:

1. `int x = scanf("%d", &employee[employee_num].salary);` What do you suppose `x` will be if I enter `"fubar\n"` as input?
2. Where do you suppose the `'f'` from `"fubar\n"` will go?
3. If it's `ungetc`'d back onto `stdin`, what would your next employee's last name be?
4. `int x = scanf("%d", &employee[employee_num].salary);` What do you suppose `x` will be if I run this code on Windows and press CTRL+Z to send `EOF` to `stdin`?
5. `int x = scanf("%d %d", &y, &z);` What would you expect `x` to be, presuming `scanf` successfully puts values into the two variables `y` and `z`?

P.S. `EOF` can be sent through `stdin` in Windows by CTRL+Z, and in Linux and friends by CTRL+D, in addition to using pipes and redirection to redirect input from other programs and files.

Comment: Thank you! Working through those questions gave me a much better understanding of what is going on when using scanf().  Correct me if I am wrong, but then I could write the stdin to an array and read the int values back to a variable using sscanf() ?

Comment: Yes, fgets and sscanf will work that way. Be aware that the %s format specifier tells sscanf to copy a *word* (eg. zero or more non-whitespace characters up to the first whitespace). What happens to the rest of your fgets'd line? This is one way your second post differs from your first.

Answer (score 2):

The Loop breaks prematurely when it encounters the break statement

```
if(strlen(strng_buffer) == 0)
        break;
```

The uninitialized character buffer `strng_buffer`, coincidently has null as the first character causing `strlen` to return `0`

I believe you may have intended

```
if(strlen(employee[employee_num].last_name) == 0)
            break;
```

as the loop terminatorm, and it was a typo in your part causing premature loop exit.

Comment: You are correct (I am a little tired). I have made an edit showing more of the code from both of my attempts. I still cannot get either one to function properly though. Someone mentioned using fgets() and then sscanf() to read in the int portion for the salary,  but I have been unable to find any clear way to do this in my searches - is it in fact a viable option?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `fgets` returns the string with the line break (`\n`) included. So, even the user presses return without entering info, the string won't be empty. Also, your buffer size for `salary` is too small.

So, either you strip out the `\n` on every `fgets` or you change your check to:

```
if(strlen(employee[employee_num].last_name) == 1) break;
```

Also, when you're getting the buffer, change 1 to something bigger, like

```
fgets(strng_buffer, 10, stdin);
```

However, if you do want to strip out the `\n` from each fgets, you can do something like:

```
employee[employee_num].last_name[strlen(employee[employee_num].last_name)-1] = 0;
```

You can do this for every string or, better yet, create a function that does it.

EDIT: if you can guarantee that the user will press enter after each input then you can safely assume this. However if it's not always the case it's possible that the last character is not `\n` and just stripping this way might cause problems.

Comment: fgets doesn't always return the string with a line break. I suggest e->last_name[strcspn(e->last_name, "\n")] = '\0'; to handle the cases when a '\n' isn't present, since your suggestion would discard a useful character, introducing a bug.

Comment: Yeah, but I was focusing on his situation in which the user is expected to press enter (and supposing there won't be an EOF). Just subtracting 1 is dangerous since `strlen` can return 0. I'll update de comment to note all that.

Comment: char strng_buffer[10]; fgets(strng_buffer, 10, stdin); What about when fgets reads 9 bytes before it reaches a '\n'?