# reading multiple variable types from single line in file C

Tags: c, string, file, input, strtok

Alright I've been at this all day and can't for the life of me get this down, maybe you chaps can help. I have a file that reads as follows

> 1301,105515018,"Boatswain","Michael R.",ABC, 123,="R01"
>
> 1301,103993269,"Castille","Michael Jr",ABC, 123,="R03"
>
> 1301,103993267,"Castille","Janice",ABC, 123,="R03"
>
> 1301,104727546,"Bonczek","Claude",ABC, 123,="R01"
>
> 1301,104731479,"Cruz","Akeem Mike",ABC, 123,="R01"
>
> 1301,105415888,"Digiacomo","Stephen",ABC, 123,="R02"
>
> 1301,106034479,"Annitto Grassis","Susan",ABC, 123,="R04"
>
> 1301,106034459,"Als","Christian",ABC, 123,="R01"

And here is my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME 15
#define MAX_SUBSEC 3
#define N 128

//void printArr(struct *students);

struct student{

int term;
int id;
char lastname[MAX_NAME];
char firstname[MAX_NAME];
char subjectname[MAX_SUBSEC];
int catalog;
char section[MAX_SUBSEC];

}students[10];

int main(){

int term;
int id;
char lastname[MAX_NAME];
char firstname[MAX_NAME];
char sub[MAX_SUBSEC];
int cat;
char sec[MAX_SUBSEC];

char fname[N];
FILE *inputf;

printf("Enter the name of the text file: ");
scanf("%123s",fname);

strcat(fname,".txt");

inputf = fopen(fname,"r");

if (inputf == NULL){

     printf("I couldn't open the file for reading.\n");
     exit(0);

}
//TROUBLE HERE!

fscanf(inputf, "%d,%d,%[^,]s", &students[0].term, &students[0].id,students[0].lastname);

printf("%d\n", students[0].term);

printf("%d\n", students[0].id);

printf("%s\n", students[0].lastname);

/*for (j = 1 ; j <= 10-1 ; j++){

    for(k = 0 ; k <= 10-2 ; k++){

        if(students[k] > students[k+1]){

            temp = students[k];
            students[k] = students[k+1];
            students[k+1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }*/

fclose(inputf);

system("pause");

return 0;

}

void printArr(int a[], int tally){

int i;

for(i = 0 ; i < tally ; i++){

 printf("%d ", a[i]);

}

printf("\n");

}
```

My objective is to take each one of those values in the text file and input it to where it belongs in the struct and subsequently the struct array, but I can't get passed the first 2 ints.

Getting the lastname string, because it is a max of 15 characters, it spills over into the first name string right after it and takes what remaining characters it needs in order to fill up the lastname char array. Obviously I do not want this. As you can see I have tried strtok but it doesnt do anything, not sure what I have to do though as I have never used it before. Also have tried just including all the variables into fscanf statement, but I either get the same output, or it becomes a mess. As it is, I am extremely lost, how do I get these values into the variables they belong?!

EDIT: updated my code, I have gotten a little farther but not much. I can now print out just the last name but can not more farther from there, I cant get to the firstname string or any of the variables beyond it.

Comment: Please don't edit your question so as to invalidate answers.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a CSV file with quoted strings, and so I would recommend you use a CSV parser (or roll your own) rather than trying to do it all with `scanf` (since `scanf` cannot deal with quotes, e.g. commas within quoted strings). A quick Google search turns up [libcsv.c](http://amath.colorado.edu/courses/management/libcsv.c) which you may be able to use in your project.

Comment: CSV file? Oh thats all just in a simple text file

Comment: ...it's comma-separated, has quoted entities, and what looks like Excel equation references. I am calling it a CSV. (Doesn't matter what the file extension is).

Comment: oh, sorry I've never heard that before!

Answer (score 2):

With the `fscanf` format string `"%d,%d,\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\",%[^,],%d,=\"%[^\"]\""` we can read a whole line's data. Besides, you have to define

```
char lastname[MAX_NAME+1];
char firstname[MAX_NAME+1];
char subjectname[MAX_SUBSEC+1];
int catalog;
char section[MAX_SUBSEC+1];
```

— the `+1` to account for the terminating '\0' character.

Comment: The `+1` is only part of the answer, but I'll give you +1 anyway.  You do need to consider the lengths to prevent buffer overflows; it would be better to use `%14[^\"]` to limit the string to the space that exists in the structure (14 being `MAX_NAME-1`), rather than allowing an extra character which then has to be handled specially.

Comment: We should combine both improvements by using `%15[^\"]`, because 14 is not enough for "Annitto Grassis", and it seems more clear to me to think of `MAX_NAME` as the maximum _length_ of a name.

Comment: But then the structure needs to use `MAX_NAME+1` too.  The length specified in the `scanf()` format does not include the terminating null.  But you're right: Annitto Grassis requires 15 characters plus a null byte.

Answer (score 1):

I have a question for you... If you want to know how to use a diamond cutter, do you try it and see, or do you consult the manual? The problem here isn't the result of your choice, but your choice itself. Believe it or not, I have answered these questions so often that I'm tired of repeating myself. The answer is all in the manual.

Read [the POSIX 2004 `scanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fscanf.html) — or the [POSIX 2008/2013 version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) — and the answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472004/how-to-use-fgets-and-sscanf-for-integers-in-loop/14472455#14472455) and you'll have some idea of what you're not doing that you should be. Even `fscanf` code should use `assert` as a debugging aid to ensure the number of items read was correct.

`%[^,]s` It seems as though there's a mistake here. Perhaps you meant `%[^,]`. The `%[` format specifier is a different format specifier to the `%s` format specifier, hence in the presumably mistaken code there are two directives: `%[^,]` and `s`. The `s` directive tells `scanf` to read an 's' and discard it.

Comment: I can understand the frustration evinced by the first paragraph, but it isn't really appropriate for SO.  The common confusion about scan sets with an `s` after them is worth pointing out, as is the manual (I've given an update to the most recent POSIX standard).  You can flag this comment for deletion (obsolete) when you've read it and fixed your answer — I'd simply delete the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

1.There is a syntax error in

```
while(result != NULL){

      printf(".....);

      ......

}

}//error
```

1. `fscanf(inputf, "%s", lastname);`  can't read a line ,`fscanf` will stop when it comes across an space

Answer (score 0):

fscanf reads one line at a time, and you can easily capture the contents of each line because your file is formatted pretty nicely, especially due to the comma separation (really useful if none of your separated values contain a comma).

You can pass fscanf a format like you're doing with "%d" to capture an int, "%s" to capture a string (ends at white space, be weary of this when for example trying to find a name like "Annitto Grassis, which would require 2 %s's), etc, from the currently read line of the file. You can be more advanced and use regex patterns to define the contents you want captured as chars, such as "Boatswain", a sequence comprised chars from the sets {A-Z}, {a-z}, and the {"}. You'll want to scan the file until you reach the end (signified by EOF in C) so you can do such and capture the contents of the line and appropriately assign the values to variables like so:

> while( fscanf(inputf, "%d,%d,%[\"A-Za-z ],%[\"A-Za-z .]", &term, &id, lastname, firstname) != EOF) {
>
> .... //do something with term, id, lastname, firstname - put them in a student struct
>
> }

For more about regex, *Mastering Regex* by Jeff Friedl is a good book for learning about the topic.

Comment: Using regexes is overkill when the OP is having basic problems with their C programming.